# Output of SQL using one column only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with column name "Val" which contains following values:

```
Val
1
2
3
4
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
1   1
2   1
2   2
3   1
3   2
3   3
4   1
4   2
4   3
4   4
```

Thanks!

Ajaysharma2061

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self join:

```
select t.val, t2.val
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.val <= t.val
order by t.val;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table on itself as if its a two different tables using the SQL join keyword. Following your attached image your SQL query is expected to be like this

```
SELECT  t.Val, c.Val
 FROM Table t, Table c
 WHERE t.id <= c.id
```

Here is a link on 
[tutorial point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm)
that can help you as well

Comment: Same as Gordon's answer, but with implicit joins. Please, don't teach people to use those... (Explicit joins are easier to write (without errors), easier to read and easier to convert to outer joins if needed.)